# Android ViewPager with all fragments of same class without transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity

I know this question has been asked many times before but I couldn't find an explanatory answer.

I want to have a single MyFragment.java and display it for all 3 pages of `ViewPager`.

But when I try to create a fragment with this method:

```
new MyFragment()
```

and add it to the `ViewPager` I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added
>               at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.setInitialSavedState(Fragment.java:679)
>               at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.ensureFragment(FragmentStateAdapter.java:269)
>               at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:175)
>               at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
>               at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
>               at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)

I'd like to know if there is any possibility to add the same fragment to ViewPager.
Possible applications of it include

> A web browser having WebView fragments in Viewpager

Why exactly do we need to use singleton fragment?
Why can't we treat fragments as recycler items which can be multiple instantiated?
Even the viewpager2 is becoming more like `RecyclerView`.

> If it is impossible to instantiate fragments repeatedly and add them
>   to the same ViewPager then are there any other ways except replacing
>   fragments in ViewPager adapter with normal inflated views? Would that
>   be a tolerable solution?

Comment: `Even the viewpager2 is becoming more like recyclerview.` Well ViewPager2 uses RecyclerView to show the views. You need to create an adapter and update it's dataset if you want to add items to viewpager2.

Comment: I'm already using viewpager2

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because when you add the fragment you don't put a distinct tag on it, so it checks whether the fragment is already added by its class. And the viewpager stores some pages in memory, so the previous fragment even though is no longer in view, is still in the memory.

When you add the fragment, give it a distinct tag

Comment: I don't use fragment transaction but instead use viewpager2 with adapter.So where do i have to set tag to fragment. Will it work if i set tag to view in onCreateView() with v.settag() ?

Comment: I found out that when i was dynamically adding fragment to the adapter i was using mFragments.add(1,myNewFragment) which i later changed to mFragments.add(mFragments.size(),myNewFragment) It fixed the problem. I wanted to add fragment at 2nd position so i was adding at 1 but i guess i need to modify that arraylist in other  way